# Enable all LinkLabel controls

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, linklabel

I have a few links which are disabled by default on a form, each using a `LinkLabel` control.

Depending on some user interaction I need to enable either one or all of the `LinkLables`.  I can enable the single `LinkLabel` just fine, but I can't find a way of enabling all of them.

In the example below I'm trying to enable all controls (as a test of my methodology), but that fails and the `LinkLabels` are not enabled at all.

Therefore my question is two part -

1. How can I identify only `LinkLabel` controls?
2. How can I loop throught these controls and enable them?

Here is what I have so far -

```
Private Sub EnableLink(Optional ByRef linkLabel As LinkLabel = Nothing)

    If linkLabel Is Nothing Then    ' Enable all links
        For Each singleLink In Me.Controls
            singleLink.Enabled = True
        Next
    Else                            ' Enable a single link
        linkLabel.Enabled = True
    End If

End Sub
```

**Bonus question** - I may need to separate my `LinkLabels` in to two sections, so is there a way of identifying `LinkLabels` which are placed within a specific control, such as a `Panel` or `TableLayoutPanel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test if a control is a `LinkLabel` using this code:

```
For Each ctrl as Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is LinkLabel Then ctrl.Enabled = True
Next ctrl
```

If you put your `LinkLabel` in a container (such as `Panel` or `TableLayoutPanel`) you can use a function like this:

```
Private Sub EnableAllLinkLabels(ByVal ctrlContainer As Control, ByVal blnEnable As Boolean)

    If ctrlContainer.HasChildren Then

        For Each ctrl As Control In ctrlContainer.Controls

            If TypeOf ctrl Is LinkLabel Then
                ctrl.Enabled = blnEnable
            ElseIf TypeOf ctrl Is Panel Or TypeOf ctrl Is TableLayoutPanel Then
                EnableAllLinkLabels(ctrl, blnEnable)
            End If          

        Next ctrl

    End If

End Sub
```

This function works also if you put a container inside another container (i.e.: a `GroupBox` in a `Panel`).

To enable all `LinkLabel` in a `Form` use this code to call the function:

```
EnableAllLinkLabels(Me, True)
```

if you want to disable only the `LinkLabel` in `Panel3` you can use this code:

```
EnableAllLinkLabels(Me.Panel3, False)
```

Comment: Sadly no dice, although good call on the addition of `as Control` in the `For Each` statement.

Comment: Is your LinkLabel already in a Panel? If yes then simply change Me.Controls in YourPanel.Controls.

Comment: Yes it is, and your suggestion works (although it's `Me.MyPanel.Controls`). Does that mean I'll always have to specify a `Panel` then? Meaning that if I do split the `LinkLabels` in to multiple `Panels` I'd first have to identify the two `Panels` and then find the `LinkLabels` within?