# Loop through every control on a Form (including those in Containers) and replace a text placeholder with a setting value

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, controls

In my project I have a setting called **DriveLetter** and I wish to insert the value of this setting in to the text of several controls on a form (replacing a placeholder).

I thought the easiest way to do this would be to loop through each control on the form and search for the placeholder, but through trial and error I have discovered that I can't do that (at least in the way I'm trying) because I make use of Containers, such as the `SplitContainer` and the `Panel`.

Below is what I have so far, which takes in to account the aforementioned `SplitContainer` and `Panel` containesr, but how can I amend this to loop through every control on the form without having to explicitly check if the current control is a type of container?

```
Private DRIVE_LETTER As String = My.Settings.DriveLetter

'**
' Handle form loading
''
Private Sub form_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ReplaceDriveLetter(Me)

End Sub

'**
' Update the value of the <DRIVE_LETTER> text placehoder
''
Private Sub ReplaceDriveLetter(ByVal ctrlContainer As Control)

    For Each ctrl As Control In ctrlContainer.Controls

        If TypeOf ctrl Is SplitContainer Or TypeOf ctrl Is Panel Then
            ReplaceDriveLetter(ctrl)
        Else
            ctrl.Text = Replace(ctrl.Text, "<DRIVE_LETTER>", UCase(DRIVE_LETTER))
        End If

    Next ctrl

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd recommend using a stack, and then if the current control contains controls, add all of these controls to the stack, and pop them if they don't contain controls. I can write an answer, I'll just need a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it, although obviously replace the text here with the DriveLetter (I can help with that if you'd like).

```
Private Sub ReplaceAllControlsOnForm()
    Dim stackOfControls As New Stack(Of Control)

    'add initial controls (all on form)
    For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
        stackOfControls.Push(c)
    Next

    'go until no controls are left
    While (stackOfControls.Count > 0)
        Dim currControl As Control = stackOfControls.Pop
        currControl.Text = "text here"
        'see if our control can contain controls
        If (currControl.Controls IsNot Nothing AndAlso currControl.Controls.Count > 0) Then
            'add all of these controls onto our stack
            For Each c As Control In currControl.Controls
                stackOfControls.Push(c)
            Next
        End If
    End While
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for posting. I'm fine adding the drive letter in, but your code is generating an error on the line ` While (stackOfControls.Peek IsNot Nothing)` - InvalidOperationException was unhandled.

Comment: @DavidGard Sorry, that worked for me but this is better I think (see edit). I changed it to just make sure the stack wasn't empty.

Comment: I've got my original solution working by including the line `If (currControl.Controls IsNot Nothing AndAlso currControl.Controls.Count > 0) Then`, rather then checking the `TypeOf` control as in my example.  So not your full code, but your code contained the key. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @DavidGard Excellent, OK. I'm glad your code is working and glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [Control.HasChildren Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.haschildren%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check if a control contains one or more child controls.

As stated on MSDN, if the `Controls` collection has a `Count` greater than zero, the `HasChildren` property will return true. Accessing the `HasChildren` property does not force the creation of a `Control.ControlCollection` if the control has no children, so referencing this property can provide a performance benefit when walking a tree of controls.

So you can change your function in:

```
Private Sub ReplaceDriveLetter(ByVal ctrlContainer As Control)

    For Each ctrl As Control In ctrlContainer.Controls

        If ctrl.HasChildren Then
            ReplaceDriveLetter(ctrl)
        Else
            ctrl.Text = Replace(ctrl.Text, "<DRIVE_LETTER>", UCase(DRIVE_LETTER))
        End If

    Next ctrl

End Sub
```

Comment: sorry if I put you on the wrong road with my example in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30776937/enable-all-linklabel-controls/30777029 ;)

Comment: Oh, `HasChildern` = my new best friend! Thanks for pointing it out, the next beer is on me ;)